# Order by doesn't show up in log

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

Well I have really simple method which should return some codes... and it does but the order by doesn't work.

```
private List<Code> get(String qualifier, ZonedDateTime validAt) {
    return em.createQuery(
              "select c\n"
            + "  from Code c\n"
            + " where c.qualifier = :qualifier\n"
            + "   and c.validFrom <= :validAt)\n"
            + "   and c.validUntil > :validAt)\n"
            + " order by c.sequence, c.code\n",
            com.service.code.impl.model.Code.class)
        .setParameter("qualifier", qualifier)
        .setParameter("validAt", validAt)
        .getResultList().stream()
        .map(converter::convert)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

When I call the method I log the statement and this is what it looks like:

```
07:59:44,158 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15) Hibernate: 
07:59:44,158 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15)     select
07:59:44,158 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15)         code0_.id as id1_0_,
07:59:44,159 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15)         code0_.changed_at as changed_at2_0_,
07:59:44,159 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15)         code0_.changed_by as changed_by3_0_,
07:59:44,159 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15)         code0_.created_at as created_at4_0_,
07:59:44,159 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15)         code0_.version as version5_0_,
07:59:44,159 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15)         code0_.code as code6_0_,
07:59:44,163 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15)         code0_.description as description7_0_,
07:59:44,163 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15)         code0_.qualifier as qualifier8_0_,
07:59:44,163 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15)         code0_.sequence as sequence9_0_,
07:59:44,163 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15)         code0_.valid_from as valid_from10_0_,
07:59:44,163 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15)         code0_.valid_until as valid_until11_0_ 
07:59:44,163 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15)     from
07:59:44,163 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15)         code code0_ 
07:59:44,163 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15)     where
07:59:44,163 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15)         code0_.qualifier=? 
07:59:44,164 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15)         and code0_.valid_from<=?
```

As you can see the order by is missing. How can that be possible?

Comment: I would say that Hibernate does the sorting on its own (i.e. in Java, not in DB).

Comment: Also the line`+ "   and c.validUntil > :validAt)\n"` are missing. You are sure that this is the executed code? Also remove `\n` from the lines. It is not necessary

Comment: There are two closing brackets in your statment without opening brackets

Comment: why do you put \n's?

Comment: I am stepping through with the debugger and this gets logged when the statement is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `)` from last two lines like this;)

```
private List<Code> get(String qualifier, ZonedDateTime validAt) {
    return em.createQuery(
              "select c\n"
            + "  from Code c\n"
            + " where c.qualifier = :qualifier\n"
            + "   and c.validFrom <= :validAt\n"
            + "   and c.validUntil > :validAt\n"
            + " order by c.sequence, c.code\n",
            com.service.code.impl.model.Code.class)
        .setParameter("qualifier", qualifier)
        .setParameter("validAt", validAt)
        .getResultList().stream()
        .map(converter::convert)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. It's strange that the statement gets executed although there are unnecessary ')'. I'll accept the answer in 8 minutes... don't know why I cannot accept it now.